# Calling a jinja2 filter with only the context as an argument

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I'm trying to render a jinja2 template in my service (not using flask, just pure jinja2 and constructing a jinja2 Environment.

Let's say I have the following filter defined

```
import jinja2

@jinja2.contextfilter
def my_function(context):
    if context.get('my_var'):
        return "hello"
    else:
        return "world"
```

Super simplified example, but the point of it is that I have some logic that conditionally returns a value based on some variable passed into the context.

Also, I'm using jinja2 2.11 or something like that, which is why I'm using `@contextfilter` instead of `@pass_context`.

I've added this filter to my environment using `env.filters['my_function'] = my_function`

In rendering the template, I'm calling

```
template = env.get_template('my_template.html')
template.render({'my_var': 'some_value'})
```

where the template might look something like

```
... some html here
{{ my_function }}
... some more html
```

This doesn't actually return "hello", and instead just is empty/blank.

I managed to get it by passing in a dummy variable

```
@jinja2.contextfilter
def my_function(context, value):
    .... code is the same
```

And then in the template, I call it with `{{ 'hi' | my_function }}`. But obviously this is just a hack and not very desirable.

So my question is, how can I call a jinja2 filter function that only takes the context in as an argument? I've tried `{{ my_function() }}` which returns the error `UndefinedError: 'my_function' is undefined`, and `{{ | my_function }}, which returns the error` TemplateSyntaxError: unexpected '|'`

Or is there some other jinja2 construct I should be using?

Edit: my suspicion is that jinja2 uses the `|` to identify a filter vs a variable, and since I don't have `|`, then it tries to just render the variable `my_function` from the context, and since it doesn't exist in the context, it just outputs an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja2 calls these kind of functions [global functions](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/?highlight=lipsum#list-of-global-functions) (like `range()`), not filters. Just change `filters` to `globals` in this line:

```
env.globals['my_function'] = my_function
```

And then you can call your function in the templates: `{{ my_function() }}`.